# Custom ArrayAdapter 'getView' method not being called upon update

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

So I have a custom list adapter I created that I'm trying to make dynamic. It starts empty, and then the user can dynamically add or remove items. Everything works fine except for one thing: the adapter's 'getView' is not being called when I **update** the adapter, and therefor the item's title - obviously - is not set (and instead it shows it's address).
Here's the code that updates the array:

```
private void newTab(String name, String url){
    _tabAdapter.add(new Article(name,url));
    _tabAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    _tabCount++;
}
```

Here's the code in the Adapter itself:

```
public class TabAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article>{
        Context _context;
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _tabCount;
        }

        public TabAdapter(Context c) {
            super(c, R.layout.tab_item);
            _context=c;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) _context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_item, parent,false);
            TextView _itemText = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
            Article getArticle = getItem(position);
            String newName = getArticle.getName();
            _itemText.setText(newName);
            return _view;
        }
    }
```

Now everything else works fine - even the OnClick works great and gets the itme's name correctly, it's just the list itself that doesn't show the item's name. I must be missing something pretty basic, but I can't find what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**: While it's not a solution to the exact problem mentioned, I managed to work around it by creating a "toString()" method for the "Article" class - so now the title shows as it should - except that it's not a very elegant solution.

Comment: Your "update" code is adding an item to the end of the list. You aren't showing us how you are changing the title of an existing item. Or are you saying that the new item you've added isn't displaying properly?

Comment: The latter. The new item is showing a memory address instead of the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor to pass the list of articles.

```
TabAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

Anytime your list gets modified, you need to re-initialize the adapter to get the updated view.

Comment: So I need to create a new instance of the adapter each time I update it?

Comment: No, that is not correct. That is the whole point of notifyDataSetChanged. You are permitted to change the backing data of an existing adapter.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem this issue might be because getView() method does get invoked when u call it but it still has the old data, there is a possibility that you have redundant copies of your List Fragment somehow and the one with the updated adapter data is not visible

you can avoid this by ListView.invalidateViews() after you update the data this might force your list to display the new data (your getView() method should be invoked).

and its very much essential you pass values in the constructor

Debug at various points and check implementation if not.

Comment: It's not being invoked at all, I've tried using breakpoints and even log writes but none are getting called. "invalidateViews()" didn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayAdapter` tracks it's own count based on the number of items in the internal backing collection. Additionally it will call `notifyDataSetChanged` internally whenever you call add unless you have explicitly disabled this by calling `setNotifyOnChange(false)`.

You should remove your `getCount` override as well as your call to `notifyDataSetChanged` as a first step toward debugging it. I don't see an obvious way that this is causing your problem, but it's good to start by simplifying your code.

Are you by chance using this adapter with a Spinner or similar widget? If so you must also override `getDropDownView` otherwise you'll get the default behavior which is to attempt to render the objects in the collection as strings.

Comment: No, it's a regular listview.